# Can phpstorm suggest variables from included files?

Tags: phpstorm, autosuggest

I have included some files in my php script using `include` and I am using variables and functions defined in my included files. Is there any way to configure PhpStorm in such way to show this kind of variables in the suggestions list?

Comment: The functions will probably work automatically, however, variables defined inside your included file may not show up if PhpStorm isn't able to resolve the full path to the included file. Anyway, did you *try*?

Comment: Of course I did try, I would not be asking this if I didn't. My question is if there is any way to configure it to get variables from files included with `require` `require_once` or `include`.
The functions do indeed show up, I put that in the title by mistake. But doesn't work that way with the variables by default.

Comment: To be honest, I mostly work in OOP situations where I don't have variables defined inside included files. A 'workaround' is to add a PhpDoc block to your file to assist PhpStorm; for example `/** @var string $myVar */`

Comment: I am new to webdevelopment and for now I really have very simple scripts so I don't really need classes and objects. But it's a good idea, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit Dec 2021:** (version 2021.2.3): option is now called "Search for variable's definition outside the current file"

Edit Jan 2021: (version 2020.1.1): option is now called "Report in files containing include statements"

Make sure the "Ignore 'include' and 'require' statements" option is *unchecked* in the `Editor > Inspections > Undefined Variable`. After doing this you will have auto-complete variables.

[image: Undefined Variable PHPStorm]

Annoyingly this doesn't give you type information about those variables, even if they're defined with accompanying PHPDoc.